# Spring dependency management pluginで依存性解決できない

Tags: java, spring, gradle

Spring dependency management pluginを使用していますが、twitter4jをdependencyに追加しましたがエラーがでて、解決してくれません。下記にbuild.gradleの内容を示します。

```
build.gradle

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath('io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.2.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 

jar {
    baseName = 'sample'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-redis')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-social-twitter')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core')
    runtime('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.7'
}
```

エラー

```
:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:.
  Required by:
      :sample:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.94 secs
```

以前に、twitter4jをバーション表記ありで追加してしまったことが原因かもしれませんが、どうすれば直りますでしょうか。Eclipse上でcleanやrefreshをしたり、`gradle clean`を実行しましたが直りませんでした。アドバイスをください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: この部分ですが `compile('org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core')` 、バージョンを入れるのではないでしょうか。例えば `compile('org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:X.Y.Z')` などです(`X.Y.Z` は実際の twitter4j のバージョン)。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ただいま外出中なので、帰宅後試してみます。

Comment: @argus 試してみました。これでビルドはできましたが、ライブラリとして認識されていないようです。

Comment: `gradle eclipse`を実行したところ認識されました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

もう解決されているようですが、一応回答しておきます。

dependency-managementプラグインは、MavenにおけるBOMを使ってバージョンを解決する仕組みをGradleに提供します。

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'io.spring.platform:platform-bom:1.1.4.RELEASE'
    }
}
```

などのようにBOMを指定して使います。
今回の場合はSpring Bootプラグインが提供するBOMが使われます。
Spring Boot 1.2.7であれば、以下から品揃えが確認できます。
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.7.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html

このBOMに含まれているプロダクトであれば、

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
```

などのようにバージョンをあえて未指定にすることで、バージョンの解決をBOMに任せることができます。
これによって、バージョン相性問題や更新時の手間が解消されます。

Twitte4Jですが、このBOMに含まれていません。
このためargus氏が指摘しているように、バージョンを明示指定する必要があります。

```
compile('org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:X.Y.Z')
```

余談ですが、Spring Boot 1.3.0からはSpring BootのGradleプラグインがdependency-managementプラグインを自動的に適用するので、build.gradleにdependency-managementの設定を明記する必要がなくなるようです。